# creating mocha test suite to start app just once

Tags: mocha.js, jestjs, spectron

I have following files

```
test1.ts
test2.ts
test3.ts
test4.ts
test5.ts
```

I want to start the tests at once with a unified before and after so that i start the application just once and run tests and close it after that

every test file has its own describe

Comment: You can create new file module that creates server once, and then returns the same singleton server for further calls

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding a file to my `test/` directory called `setup.spec.ts` that performs the setup & teardown using mochas before & after hooks. These hooks are run before/after any describe block in your other test files.

```js
import {setupApp, teardownApp} from '../src/helpers/app';

before(async () => {
  await setupApp();
});

after(async () => {
  await teardownApp();
});
```